# how to retrieve what's in a data_value ? With selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
path = "c:/users/admin/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


driver.get("https://donboscosdw.smartschool.be/login")

# Input fields
username = driver.find_element_by_name("login_form[_username]")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("login_form[_password]")
time.sleep(2)

username.clear()
password.clear()

# Login to website 
username.send_keys("...")
password.send_keys("...")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


class Notifications:
    ls = []

    # check for new messages 

    messages=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="smscTopContainer"]/nav/div[4]/button/span').get_property('data_value')
    print(type(messages))
```

i want selenium to open my messages if i get a new one. But when i try to get the `data_value` . It returns `None`.  But i want to retrieve whatever is in the data_value .

Comment: you're sure the value is in the `data_value` attribute. You can see it in the HTML

Comment: @MrBrN197 yes :  whenever i receive a new message the value in data_value increase. ps. the value in `data_value` that i'm trying to get is a integer .

Comment: When you say It returns `NoValue`. I've never seen that in python... Can you tell me the exact Result. is It `None`

Comment: @MrBrN197 I am terrible sorry.  I wrote the wrong thing , yes i meant to say None.   Once again i am sorry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
path = "c:/users/admin/appdata/local/programs/python/python38-32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


driver.get("https://donboscosdw.smartschool.be/login")

# Input fields
username = driver.find_element_by_name("login_form[_username]")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("login_form[_password]")
time.sleep(2)

username.clear()
password.clear()

# Login to website
username.send_keys("...")
password.send_keys("...")
username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# check for a new message 

class Notifications:
    email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='smscTopContainer']/nav/div[4]/button/span"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
    email = str(email)

    # if i have received new message open mail ,else print no message

    if email > str("0"):
        open_email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="smscTopContainer"]/nav/div[4]/button')
        open_email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    else : 
        print("No New Messages")
```

I found a solution to the problem . You need to use `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`. which will return the value in the `data_value` and not a `NoneType`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to activate `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` before getting the data.

With the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can write :

```
email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.xpath, "//*[@id='smscTopContainer']/nav/div[4]/button/span"))).get_attribute("value")
print (email)
```

Comment: @bliboy While using Selenium, this approach within this answer should be the ideal way.